# How do different types of handlebar tape do in the rain?

Tags: rain, handlebar-tape

I'm planning to replace the handlebar tape (nonabsorbent, basic plastic tape with no padding) on my commuter bike, and I was looking to switch to cork tape.  However, I always park it outside and it occasionally rains, so I was wondering if the cork's absorbency would be a problem.  Also, what about leather and other tape types?

Comment: I generally use hockey tape, and I've never had any problems with it in the rain.  It doesn't offer much "padding", though.

Comment: Leather will suffer in the rain.

Comment: Bar tape is a consumable, and is a cheap way to dress up your bike.  I change mine two or three times a year, but I only use cheap tape.

Comment: @Criggie Yeah, I know. I just don't want to replace it after every rain, or have mildew growing on it or something .

Comment: If your bike grows mildew, you need to revise how and where you store it.

Comment: @Criggie Not the bike, the bar tape. I dunno what things mildew does and doesn't grow on, which is why I asked the original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is very little actual cork in most cork tapes. The plastic foam absorbs some water and may become slightly slippery, but it doesn't deteriorate or anything.

Answer (score 1):

Lizard Skin DSP tape does pretty good at getting wet, and stays grippy, even when wet.  But be aware, it isn't very durable.  I've "barely scratched" it on a brick wall and torn it in half before.

Comment: Its also quite expensive, can't be stretched too far and doesn't take kindly to sharp bends or sharp wrapping patterns.